# Grab cover image of uploaded video

Tags: video, jwplayer

We allow users to upload their videos on the website in flv, mp4 and mov formats and use jwplayer to show these videos.

The problem is how do we make cover images for these videos?

I know it's straight-forward to show a particular jpg as a cover image on jwplayer. My question is how do we generate the jpg file from an uploaded video file.

- Is there an option on jwplayer that will show a cover image from a file that is given to it.
- Is this something we need to manage from the server side by running some command-line utility to grab an image and then use that?

Answer (score 2):

"Is there an option on jwplayer that will show a cover image from a file that is given to it."

No, but you can set a variable called "image" in your player setup, which is will point to an image file on your server.

```
image: "something.jpg",
```

For example.

You can also use our JavaScript API to fake this, like so - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1439795-example-a-poster-less-preview

```
<div id="myElement"></div>

<script>
  jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    file: "/uploads/myVideo.mp4",
    autostart: true,
    mute: true,
    controls: false
  });
</script>

<script>
  setTimeout(function() { 
    jwplayer().pause();
    jwplayer().setMute(false);
    jwplayer().setControls(true);
  },3000);
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Ethan! but do you think this is okay if its done for 15 - 20 videos on a single page.. in terms of performance..?

Comment: Np. That might be a bit much since it would be basically downloading / buffering all of the movies at the same time. It might not be good for bandwidth costs to do that, not sure about performance. I would try it out to see what you think, though.